# alternative solution to fussed lasso

Tags: optimization, lasso, regularization, constrained-optimization, fused-lasso

The question is related to [strange result from fused lasso estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576847/strange-result-from-fused-lasso-estimator)

Let us consider fussed lasso estimator:

$$
\hat{\beta}^{FL}  = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} [(y_{i} - \beta_{i})^{2} + \lambda_{1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|\beta_{i} - \beta_{i+1}| + \lambda_{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\beta_{i}|],
$$

From [PATHWISE COORDINATE OPTIMIZATION](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-statistics/volume-1/issue-2/Pathwise-coordinate-optimization/10.1214/07-AOAS131.full) it follows that the solution is given by the following: let
$$
\hat{\beta}^{F}  = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} [(y_{i} - \beta_{i})^{2} + \lambda_{1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|\beta_{i} - \beta_{i+1}|],
$$
then
$$
\hat{\beta}^{FL}  = \underset{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} [(\hat{\beta}^{F}_{i} - \alpha_{i})^{2} + \lambda_{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\alpha_{i}|],
$$
i.e. first, one can perform fusion, and then we apply lasso to the fussed signal.

**The question:** is the following procedure correct?

Let us, first, solve the dual to Lagrange's form of fusion for some $s_{1}>0$:

$$
\hat{\beta}^{*F}  = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} [(y_{i} - \beta_{i})^{2}] \, \text{ subject to } \,  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|\beta_{i} - \beta_{i+1}| \leq s_{1},
$$
then, apply lasso to $\hat{\beta}^{*F}$:
$$
\hat{\xi}  = \underset{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} [(\hat{\beta}^{*F}_{i} - \alpha_{i})^{2} + \lambda_{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\alpha_{i}|].
$$

Then, we can say that
$$
\hat{\xi} = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} [(y_{i} - \beta_{i})^{2} + \lambda^{*}_{1}(y,s_{1}) \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|\beta_{i} - \beta_{i+1}| + \lambda_{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\beta_{i}|],
$$

i.e. there exists some $\lambda^{*}_{1}$, which depends on the signal and $s_{1}$.

Comment: You can find a common algorithm to solve LASSO, smooth LASSO, fusion LASSO and elastic net in [Nesterov's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-012-0629-5). You can also refer to Sara van de Geer's paper: https://doi.org/10.1214/11-EJS638.

Comment: the question is not about how to solve (there is R package available). I am more into theory and wonder if my conclusion is correct.